# Adding datarows to datagrid from database

Tags: c#, .net, database, sql-server-2008

I'm new to databases. I'm trying to make a search utility to match user input string with records in database and display them.

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con;
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter da;
DataSet ds1;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
        ds1 = new DataSet();

        con.ConnectionString = "";

        con.Open();

        string sql = "SELECT * From tblLecturers";
        da = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);

        da.Fill(ds1, "Lecturers");

        con.Close();
    }

    Form2 secondForm = new Form2();

    private void btnFind_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        secondForm.Show();

        string searchFor = textBox1.Text;
        int results = 0;
        int i;

        DataRow[] returnedRows; 

        if (radioButton1.Checked)
        {
            returnedRows = ds1.Tables["Lecturers"].Select("Name like '%" + searchFor + "%'");
        }
        else
        {
            returnedRows = ds1.Tables["Lecturers"].Select("Department like '%" + searchFor + "%'");
        }

        results = returnedRows.Length;

        if (results > 0)
        {
            secondForm.dataGridView1.DataSource = returnedRows;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No such Record");
        }

    }
```

There's no error but it's just displaying a blank grid. returnedRows contains all the rows whose contents match the user input. I'm pretty sure this isn't though:

```
            secondForm.dataGridView1.DataSource = returnedRows;
```

Tried rows.add using for loop, won't work. How do i do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code has problems with SQL injection. You should use parameterized queries or else correctly escape user input.

Comment: Not sure i follow. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Well imagine what would happen to your program if someone tried to search for `O'Reilly`. Or just try it yourself and see. This comment box is too small for me to go into all the details so I'd advise you to research SQL injection and how to avoid it before writing any more code.

Comment: This could all be much cleaner and simpler if you used Linq for your selection methods instead of even parameterized queries. Have you attempted to call `secondForm.dataGridView1.Refresh()` to make sure it repaints itself?

Answer (score 0):

Call the BindMethod of gridView

```
  if (results > 0)
    {
        secondForm.dataGridView1.DataSource = returnedRows;
        secondForm.dataGridView1.DataBind();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No such Record");
    }
```

Comment: Says there's no extension method DataBind for dataGridView1. Incidentally, is databind needed for windows forms applications?

Comment: 0 down vote
 

Ignore DataBind method, there is no method for windows GridView. The datarow array can be added to dataset or datatable, using the dataset or datatable we can directly bind the GridView

Comment: I created a new dataSet and then added the dataRows:

    dataSet dt = new dataSet();
    dt.Merge(returnedRows);
    secondForm.dataGridView1.DataSource = returnedRows;

No display.

Answer (score 0):

Ignore DataBind method, there is no method for windows GridView.
The datarow array can be added to dataset or datatable, using the dataset  or datatable we can directly bind the GridView

Comment: This is a comment rather than an answer. It looks like the comment you left on your own answer before. You should probably go ahead and delete this one.